# What part of this code is not iteratable?

Tags: python, built-in, iterable

I get the "main loop 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" error when I run the code below. The error occurs in 
for word_search in search_list:

I can't figure out what the built-in function or method is.

```
end_search=[]
#Remove punctuation
for word_search in search_list:

    #Find punctuation
    if word_search.find('"')>0:
        word_search=word_search.replace('"','')
    if word_search.find("'")>0:
        word_search=word_search.replace("'",'')

    end_search.append(word_search)
```

This is part of a program to read a text file and return the occurrences of words given in a different text file

Comment: But have you **defined** `search_list` yourself? If so, show how.

Comment: what's 'search_list'?

Answer (score 0):

So, I just ran the code you provided as such:

```
search_list = ["hi ' my ' name ' is ' jeremiah", 'this "is " a " list " of " strings']
end_search=[]
#Remove punctuation
for word_search in search_list:

    #Find punctuation
    if word_search.find('"')>0:
        word_search=word_search.replace('"','')
    if word_search.find("'")>0:
        word_search=word_search.replace("'",'')

    end_search.append(word_search)

print(end_search)
```

It worked fine.

```
>>>['hi  my  name  is  jeremiah', 'this is  a  list  of  strings']
```

This leads me to believe the problem is in `search_list`.  Are you making it an actual list before you try to iterate through it or are you trying to iterate through a function or method called `search_list`?  If the case is the latter, it still might work if you iterate through `search_list()`, but you are better off explicitely creating a list to iterate through just to make sure you avoid funky glitches.